# Sony Xperia SP: Set Bootloader unlock allowed to yes

Tags: android, bootloader, sony, sony-xperia

I was redirected here from https://developer.sonymobile.com/about/how-do-i-get-in-contact/

I have a Sony Xperia SP without SIM lock and without contract of any network carrier. I want to switch to LineageOS and need to unlock the bootloader. But the Rooting status is 'Bootloader unlock allowed: No'. How can I change this setting to Yes? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a dedicated Android question and does not address any programming aspect.

Comment: Sorry, if I am in the wrong place, but as I mentioned, Sony themselves directed me here. So if you wish to close this question, please tell me how to contact Sony developers instead. Thanks.

Comment: Android questions belong to https://android.stackexchange.com or you just go to the "rooting source" (xda-developers forum).